# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0.'

Tags: c#, json, api, zipcode

I am using an API from Zip-Code.com whereby I am feeding it 3 variable (zip code, minimum distance, max distance) and it returns all zip codes along with city names in that radius. I am able to send the request and I do get a response but when i try and deserialize the json into my object I am getting the following error:
(Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0.') 
Below is my code as well as some of the commented out code that I tried but been unsuccessful with.

```
class Worker
{

    string zipAPIKey = "MYAPIKEY";
    string requestURL = "https://api.zip-codes.com/ZipCodesAPI.svc/1.0/";
    RootObject ZipCodesObject = new RootObject();


    public int DoWork()
    {
        GetZips();

        return 0;
    }



    public RestRequest CreateRequest(string endPoint, Method method)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(endPoint, method);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.Method = method;
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");


        return request;
    }
    public void GetZips()
    {
        int minimumRadius = 0;
        int maxRadius = 20;
        string ZipCode = "40291";

        List<string> ZipList = new List<string>();

        var client = new RestClient(requestURL);
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri(requestURL);
        RestRequest request = CreateRequest(@"FindZipCodesInRadius?zipcode="+ZipCode+"&maximumradius="+maxRadius+"&minimumradius="+minimumRadius+"&key="+zipAPIKey, Method.GET);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);


        //Console.WriteLine(response.Content.GetType());
        //string removed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content).ToString();
        //removed.Substring(1);
        //JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.Content);
        //response.Content.Trim(new char[] { '\uFEFF', '\u200B' });
        //string result = response.Content;
        //result = JToken.Parse(result).ToString();
        //Console.WriteLine(result);
        //result = JToken.Parse(response.Content).ToString();
        //Console.WriteLine(result);

        string json = new StreamReader(response.Content).ReadToEnd();//This fails with the same error that the DeserializeObject statement below fails with.
        Console.WriteLine(json);


        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            ZipCodesObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);// This is where I get the error


        }
    }
}
```

The response am receiving when printed to the Console shows a question mark at the beginning.

```
?{
  "DataList": [
    {
      "Code": "40291",
      "City": "LOUISVILLE",
      "State": "KY",
      "Latitude": 38.131191000000,
      "Longitude": -85.574576000000,
      "County": "JEFFERSON"
    }//This is just the first result from the API.
```

When hovering over the response.Content it shows me this----->
[What the response looks like before choosing a view mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B33sw.jpg)

What am I missing here? I have tried several things but just cannot manage to get it to work properly. Thanks!

Comment: Can you put in a break point and inspect response.Content and add what the data looks like to your post?

Comment: Are you getting getting System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK  (which is 200) or other value?

Comment: What's the question mark doing there?

Comment: I do get a status code of OK.

Comment: @nineBerry Thats what im trying to figure out. I've read things that say I might be double serializing the object but Ive tried removing or commenting out parts that were serializing the Json but still had no luck. Ive also seen where trying to parse the item in different ways sometimes helps but ive tried those as well and still dont get the results i am looking for. I have also tried several different types of trimming to get rid of the ? but still had no luck.

Comment: You should create a ZipCodeClass with all the object members from each zip code and deserialize into a List<ZipCodeClass>.

Comment: The attempt using StreamReader will not work, because when passing a string as the parameter to the StreamReader constructor, this will be treated as a filepath.

Comment: Try to write respone.Content to a file and look what the beginning of that file looks like with a hex editor.

Comment: Also, please show the exact code that was used to output the response to the console so that there was the question mark. This is not clear from the code in your question

Comment: string result = response.Content;
Console.WriteLine(result);

That is what gets me the the console which shows the question mark.

Comment: I printed the Response.Content to a text file and it does not contain the question mark or any other character at the beginning. It looks like a totally normal json object.